# Two Classes To Show Active Style

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/27nbt2ax/)

```
<li class="HIS-Magnifier Menu-Drop Active"></li>
```

The above snippet and viewable on JSFiddle, upon becoming 'Active' I would like to show the active style for both HIS-Magnifier & Menu-Drop however I can only seem to achieve one or the other to display their active class.

I am not sure if I am beating around the bush for my simple progress so far after I have taken an 8 month break due to complications, hopefully doable and a minor mishap?...

### Active Class

```
.Menu-Drop.Active {
    background:url(...) repeat-x;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1a800;
    border-top: 1px solid #d1a800;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1a800;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

And one icon active;

```
.HIS-List.Active { background-position: -28px -8px; }
.HIS-List.Active:hover { background-position: -105px -8px; }
```

Comment: `upon becoming 'Active' I would like to show the active style for both HIS-Magnifier & Menu-Drop ` what is the active style?

Comment: Hiya @guradio I'll update the question now, they are in the JSFiddle; Icon changes colour & background is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make .HIS-Magnifier style important

```
background-image: url(http://rafflebananza.com/RaffleBananza-NEW/Desktop/Assets/IMG/default/TopNav/IconSet.png) !important;
```

Comment: this makes the icons work however [this image](http://rafflebananza.com/RaffleBananza-NEW/Desktop/Assets/IMG/default/TopNav/24px-Yellow-Bg-90-opacity.png) is still not showing. I can implement more div's however I thought this would be easilly achieved...

Comment: you can only use one background-image for the html tag, so to solve it you will need to change the html a little bit, give the li the background image, and inside the li add <img> with the icon that you want.

Comment: but it is better to use background-color instead of background-image

Comment: Not quite the result but good enough for people needing this help in the future so +1 :)